# Memory Leak using react useState and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a component that will continously fetch data from an api

(on real use the response would take some time, so it wont get called all the time)

So I created this custom hook to do it

```js
export const callUpdateApi = (url) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ data: null, loading: true });

useEffect(() => {
  setState(state => ({ data: state.data, loading: true }));
  axios.get(url)
    .then(x => {
      return x.data
    } , err => {
        console.log('CALL UPDATE API ERROR ')
        // timer to try again later if request fail
        setTimeout(function(){
          console.log('err status', err);
          setState({...state , data: null})
      } , 3000)
    } )
    .then(y => {
      setState({ data: y, loading: false });
    });
}, [state.data]);

return state;    
};
```

then, if I call it the memory usage will go up as time go on.

**If I set so my api responds quickly,in minutes my memory is almost full**

Comment: try useState({ data: null, loading: true }, [])

Comment: Are you running this code with the browser's debug tools open? If so, the Network tab will capture the response of every request and take up more and more memory as time goes on. Either way, I think you need some kind of timing mechanism to ensure that your page isn't repeatedly querying the backend in rapid fire. That's just not good.

Comment: I guess it was the debug tools as you mentioned, I'm new to front end development

Comment: The timing mechanism is handled on my backend